# How to Deploy pingfederate in tomcat7?

Tags: tomcat7, pingfederate

```
Can anyone say me the steps to deploy ping federate in tomcat 7.
```

Since i am new to ping federate i don't know how to deploy ping federate in tomcat 7. Can anyone help me to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

There is no need (or ability) to deploy PingFederate under Tomcat. It is entirely self-contained. All you basically need to do is point it at the JDK. Please review the [installation documentation](http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF72/Installation).